# Is it possible to copy and paste Jupyter Notebook cells from other notebooks and have the new notebook be able to call the variables declared?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm basically training a bunch of models and I decided it'd be best to train them all separately and after they're all done, copy and paste the cells and outputs into one file. However, if I were to want to plot something with the data, as far as I know calling the variables if they were not initialised in that file would result in an error and so I would be forced to train the model all over again on that file. Is there a way around this?

Comment: To start simple, try saving your model in the pickle format in the first notebook and read the model in the second notebook. This is one of the comprehensive blog : https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/

If you want to share the variables between 2 notebooks, try using %store  magic